# Что лучше выбрать TextView или WebView?

Tags: android, webview, textview

Добрый день, я хочу написать приложение справочник, которое в себе будет содержать форматированный текст, как в html, также будет присутствовать текст выделенный другим цветом, и картинки.

Сейчас я применяю для форматирования текста метод `quantityTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textString, htmlImageGetter, null));`

А для отображения картинок

```
Html.ImageGetter htmlImageGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {
        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            Resources resources = getResources();
            int resId = resources.getIdentifier(source, "drawable", getPackageName());
            Drawable ret = resources.getDrawable(resId);
            ret.setBounds(0, 0, ret.getIntrinsicHeight(), ret.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return ret;
        }
};
```

И все это вывожу в TextView.

Но как я писал выше, мне нужно больше гибкости, к примеру работа с изображением. Я бы хотел чтобы изображение было в центре и имел адаптивность под экраны. Это вообще возможно реализовать в TextView или лучше выводить информацию через WebView ?

Answer (score 2):

- WebView более гибкий в плане настройки внешнего вида содержимого, но более прожорлив
- TextView дает лучшую производительность в списках (listview, gridview, ...), но кроме вставки форматированого текста сложно что-то получить с хорошей производительностью.

Если есть возможность использовать в списке (продуктов, товаров, наименований) TextView то используйте его, а на самой карточке товара используйте WebView для отображения полной информации о товаре.

Comment: Я сделал шаблон из двух TextView, куда подставляется разная информация из БД. Информация может быть сгруппированной по разном. И вот поэтому у меня не получается сделать вид текущей страницы читабельным. Картинка если она большая на планшете отображается, а если это будет телефон, то полностью не влазит. А Если всего будет открыта одна  WebView - которая будет отвечать за отображения контента, это же сильно не повлияет на производительность? Это будет обычный справочник, с минимум функционала.

Comment: где можно посмотреть на то что сейчас у вас есть?

Comment: [ссылка](http://priscree.ru/img/0530e9bd536ba9.jpg) вот так выгладит приложение